# JAVA: Virtual Mouse

Tags: java, applet, mouse, awtrobot

Is it possible to simulate all mouse functions without using the mouse native to the OS?
Is it possible to create a virtual mouse within the confines of a JFrame?

This mouse should be able to interact with all components of the JFrame and act as a normal mouse. This mouse should be able to interact with the JFrame while it is minimized/Not visible.

I have tried using "java.awt.Robot", however this uses the mouse and keyboard of the OS.
Also I will be using this to interact with an applet which draws all its graphics and has custom components so I will not be able to fake mouse/keyboard events that way.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? What is your *real* problem?

Comment: I want to make an efficient bot, learn how they work, so I can be better suited to protect myself against them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the reflection library to get the MouseListener methods and invoke them.

For what are you trying to make a bot?

And you can't protect yourself against bots, look at Runescape.

You can add me on Skype to talk about this topic.

Example:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///" + "C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\Game.jar")});
ClassWithApplet = loader.loadClass("AppletClass");
Applet applet = (Applet) ClassWithApplet.newInstance();
    MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(applet, 501, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, x, y, 1, false, left ? 1 : 3);
((MouseListener) applet).MousePressed(me);
```

Comment: Ayyyyeee, I was looking for this exactly for making an RS bot! Hope crap. That was funny.